# vb.net resx to translate windows forms application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, translate, resx

I am building a Windows Forms application, which I want to be able to translate. I tried to create two RESX files, one for each language, but I don't know how to access to the string contained in there. What I want to achieve is something like:

```
ResourceManager.get(control.tag)
```

But I've tried in many ways and haven't got it to work.

I can actually access to the resources contained in the built-in resources file...

```
My.Resources.aKeyInThere
```

But my project is becoming bigger and bigger, and I want some kind of Getter method which receives a key and gives me the value.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager?view=netframework-4.8) helpful?

Comment: @XingyuZhao i'll give it a deeper look as soon as I get home. After a fast read, it looks complicated and not exactly what I'm looking for, but I read it slow and will tell you. Thank you for taking time trying to help me, I really appreciate it!! Have a nice day!